# Git don't push a symfony bundle into Github

Tags: git, symfony, github, push, bundle

I'm working on symfony project and using **git** and **github** for the version control.

The problem that I met was, after creating a new project on [github.com/kouuki/CROWDRISEPIDEV](https://github.com/kouuki/CROWDRISEPIDEV)

I've pushed the folder containing the whole project in my PC which it also contains the **FOSUserBundle**, I did not find any folder or files under `CROWDRISEPIDEV/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` which makes impossible to my friend to work with me on that project !

So what I have to do to push all those files

Comment: You should mark your questions as answered when they are.

Answer (score 3):

The `vendor` directory is never added to the VCS repository.

You need to install [composer](http://getcomposer.org) and run `composer install` after cloning the project.

This will recreate the `vendor` directory and install all required packages into.
Required packages are found in your `composer.json` and downloaded by `composer`.

After a `git pull`, the vendor will not be removed because it's ignored by your `.gitignore`, also you don't need to run the `composer install` command.

See more in the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and [How to Create and Store a Symfony Project in Git](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#managing-vendor-libraries-with-composer-json)

Comment: What I understand after some research is the fosuser folder is considered as submodule and i have to tracked as a submodule and push it

Comment: No, never add a 3rd party bundle to your git repository. You will need to upgrade it as long as it evolves, and don't write code into. Vendors are never sub version. See [How to Create and Store a Symfony Project in Git](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#managing-vendor-libraries-with-composer-json)